# Understanding Blind Vulnerabilities

Tags: security, xss

There is something i wonder. I am giving an example of XSS. We say it is divided into 3 types. Blind, Reflected and stored. There is no one who does not know reflected and stored. We say that the attacker is not informed about the vulnerable with a blind at the beginning of it's name, but if there is no information, how does the attacker understand that there is any vulnerable?

Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0):

In blind XSS the attacker typically doesn't know if his attack will succeed at first.
You can think of it like setting up a trap. You don't know if it will succeed, or if the victim has protection, you are blind.

Actually, blind XSS vulnerabilities are a variant of stored (persistent) XSS vulnerabilities. The attacker's input is saved by a web server and then executed as a malicious script in another application or in another part of the application.

For example, an attacker injects a malicious payload into a contact/feedback form and POST it (setting up a trap). Let's say the info sent is then served by another application or in another part of the app:

The admin is opening his admin panel/dashboard to view feedback from his users. When the administrator of the application is reviewing the feedback entries - the attacker’s payload will be loaded and executed.

The attacker was blind - he didn't know if the server side of that form sanitize the input, or if the "admin panel" of the application has any protection against JS execution.

Example of web applications and web pages where blind XSS attacks can occur:

- Contact/Feedback pages
- Log viewers
- Exception handlers
- Chat applications / forums
- Customer ticket applications
- Web Application Firewalls
- Any application that requires user moderation

In the case of blind XSS, the payload can be executed after a long period of time when the administrator visits the vulnerable page. It can take hours, days, or even weeks until the payload is executed.
Therefore, this type of vulnerability is much harder to detect compared to other reflected XSS vulnerabilities where the input is reflected immediately.